# Date and time functions in BigQuery's Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I was trying to use one of my MSSQL queries on BigQuery's new standard SQL feature, as it requires special JOIN conditions. However, the reference doesn't contain any explanations of the date time functions in BigQuery's standard SQL yet.

So far I managed to convert my DATE_ADD statements
from: *DATE_ADD('2015-01-01', -13, 'MONTH')*
to: *DATE_ADD('2015-01-01', INTERVAL -13 MONTH)*

I also converted YEAR(x) to EXTRACT(YEAR FROM x). Both seem to be MySQL-like statements.

Lastly I noticed the output of most date functions must be converted using TIMESTAMP before you can compare them.

But now that my query finally wants to run I get an *"Internal error"*. Anyone know what could be wrong? This is the query:

```
SELECT
  M,
  Bought12MBeforeM,
  Bought12MBeforeAndInM,
  (Bought12MBeforeAndInM * 1.0) / (Bought12MBeforeAndInM + Bought12MBeforeM) AS RepurchaseRate
FROM (
  SELECT
    M,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MaxM < TIMESTAMP(M) THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS Bought12MBeforeM,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MaxM >= TIMESTAMP(M)
      AND MinM < TIMESTAMP(M) THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS Bought12MBeforeAndInM
  FROM (
    SELECT
      M,
      user_id,
      MAX(cart_creation_date) AS MaxM,
      MIN(cart_creation_date) AS MinM
    FROM (
      SELECT
        user_id,
        cart_creation_date
      FROM
        `vex-eu-cloud-sql-001.work_user.flat_orders`
      WHERE
        cart_creation_date >= TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD('2015-01-01', INTERVAL -13 MONTH))
      GROUP BY
        user_id,
        cart_creation_date ) UniqueCarts
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
        DATE(Day) AS M
      FROM
        `vex-custom.wouter.days_2007_2020`
      WHERE
        EXTRACT(YEAR
        FROM
          Day) >= 2015
        AND EXTRACT(DAY
        FROM
          Day) = 1
        AND Day < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) ) Months
    ON
      cart_creation_date > TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(M, INTERVAL -13 MONTH))
      AND cart_creation_date < TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(M, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
    GROUP BY
      M,
      user_id ) BoughtInM
  GROUP BY
    M ) Results
```

Comment: If you provide job id, I can look up what caused the Internal Error

Comment: Hi Mosha, it's **vex-production:bquijob_343984cc_1545ef2e7a4**

Comment: OK, I updated the answer after investigating that failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to a bug handling TIMESTAMP in the WHERE clause in standard SQL. The current workaround is to wrap it with UNIX_MICROS function to translate from TIMESTAMP to INT64, then your query works:

```
SELECT
  M,
  Bought12MBeforeM,
  Bought12MBeforeAndInM,
  (Bought12MBeforeAndInM * 1.0) / (Bought12MBeforeAndInM + Bought12MBeforeM) AS RepurchaseRate
FROM (
  SELECT
    M,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MaxM < TIMESTAMP(M) THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS Bought12MBeforeM,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MaxM >= TIMESTAMP(M)
      AND MinM < TIMESTAMP(M) THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS Bought12MBeforeAndInM
  FROM (
    SELECT
      M,
      user_id,
      MAX(cart_creation_date) AS MaxM,
      MIN(cart_creation_date) AS MinM
    FROM (
      SELECT
        user_id,
        cart_creation_date
      FROM
        `vex-eu-cloud-sql-001.work_user.flat_orders`
      WHERE
        UNIX_MICROS(cart_creation_date) >= UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD('2015-01-01', INTERVAL -13 MONTH)))
      GROUP BY
        user_id,
        cart_creation_date ) UniqueCarts
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
        DATE(Day) AS M
      FROM
        `vex-custom.wouter.days_2007_2020`
      WHERE
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Day) >= 2015
        AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM Day) = 1
        AND UNIX_MICROS(Day) < UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE())) ) Months
    ON
      cart_creation_date > TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(M, INTERVAL -13 MONTH))
      AND cart_creation_date < TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(M, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
    GROUP BY
      M,
      user_id ) BoughtInM
  GROUP BY
    M ) Results
```

Comment: OK, tried that but got this: _Error: TIMESTAMP_ADD does not support the MONTH date part_

Comment: The reference mentions YEAR, DAY, and other date part functions. But all of those give me: _Error: Function not found: YEAR_

Comment: I will update documentation to make it clear that dateparts such as YEAR and DAY should be used inside EXTRACT function.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Mosha. The query ran twice successfully but now I'm getting resources exceeded error. The EACH keyword is no longer supported?

Comment: There is no EACH in SQL standard, and all the JOINs and GROUP BYs should work fine without it, please provide job id of failed query, we can take a look.

Comment: Thanks Mosha, here's the job id:  vex-buckets:bquijob_2b0e4917_1547041e9d0